# If $x_n\cdot y_n\to 0$ then $x_n \to 0$ or $y_n \to 0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Assume

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_ny_n}=0$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{x_n}=0$$ or $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{y_n}=0$$

I couldnt find two series who disprove that..
just hint please
thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: consider two sequences whose values bounce back and forth so that neither converges, but the product does.

Comment: As an example: $x_n=1+(-1)^n$ and $y_n=1+(-1)^{n+1}$

Answer (score 4):

Consider $x_n = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if $n$ is even}\\ 1 & \text{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$ and $y_n=1-x_n$.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true.  Consider two sequences each of which have no limit as $n \to \infty$ because they oscillate between $0$ and $1$:
$$
x_n = n \mod 2 \\ y_n = (n+1) \mod 2
$$
Then 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} x_ny_n = 0$$
but the individual sequences have no such limit.